# How to limit number of users and/or threads for a .net library?

Tags: c#, .net, threadpool

How can we limit the number of users and/or threads for a .net library?

We want to have different library editions for different user groups:
1) Single user: Max 1 user with 1 thread

2) Multiple user with max 50 users and/or threads
As an example, this edition can accommodate 50 users can have each 1 thread, or 25 users with each 2 threads

3) Multiple user with max 100 users and/or threads
.. and so on.

How can we do this the easiest way with c#?
Selina

Comment: Semaphores are there for exactly this purpose...

Answer (score 2):

Define a sempahore and synchronize on it:

```
static readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new Semaphore(50);

...

//before your library does anything
semaphore.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120)); //timeout to prevent deadlocks
```

Fortunately, everything that you need is built into this class.

You should probably add a wait timeout or you risk causing deadlocks and your customers will deem your library unreliable. If the wait times out you should probably just allow the access.

Comment: Thanks. Where does semaphore.Release() come in, or is there no need to use it?

Comment: Can SemaphoreSlim prevent users accessing the library from another process on the same computer?

Comment: If you want to, yes. You can create a named object which is shared between processes. You need to use `Semaphore` for that, though.

Comment: Two questions: (1) Is it then not strictly necessary to use Semaphore instead of SemaphoreSlim if we want to limit number of users and threads on a computer? (2) You said "After the call to the library is done". How can this be done within the library?

Comment: (1) yes, I did not realize you need this cross-process. (2) My understanding is that users call your library. You want at most N concurrent calls active. So you `Wait` on enter and `Release` on exit.